# How to fill image without stretching the image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Site URL: http://theneonplanet.com.au/home-2-2/

Hi, I am working on this wordpress website. I use divi theme but I manually change things with css.

[second section image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p0Gh.png)

this is currently placed in the recent stories section.

The problem is that the post image is placed correctly but it is stretched inside the div and it looks very strange; the picture is not suppose to be this thin.
I want the image to be filled inside the div. which means it doen't need to be the same width of the div but it has to fill the space.

is there any code solution for this?
I tried object-fit, and min and max height. both didn't work..

Comment: There are numerous approaches from custom css to responsive frameworks. Specificity might help provide a solution that best fits your needs.  For example... you could just set it as a background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to make an image fill a div element using CSS. The easiest way would be to set the image as the `background-image` of the div and set the `background-size` to `cover`. You can also set the `background-position` to align the image.

```
div {
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

**But in your case**, you seem to be using a WordPress plug-in which inserts the image as an `img` tag inside the div and stretching the image to the size of the div. So we can use the `object-fit` CSS property on the `img` element to make the image fill the size of the `img` element.

Your code will look something like this.

```
#tesco-slider .et_pb_slide_image img {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

Just as with the `background-image` approach, `object-fit: cover` will make your image fill the size of the `img` tag and `object-position: center` will align the image to the center.

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a useful way. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong, and is also not useful for future readers.

Comment: @ThimalW I will gladly upvote you if you do. Respond here if you do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @GrumpyCrouton I'll update my answer.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Updated the answer. Hope this is an improvement.

Comment: @ThimalW Thank you very much. You should apply my reasoning to _every question you answer_. I reverted my downvote to an upvote, thank you for the edit.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thank you. I'll keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 0):

use  `background-size: cover;` attribute in your `css` for the background image

Comment: the images are coming from blog posts.

Comment: pass them to inline style as `background image` instead of `image src`